# How to configure rustfmt in the bazel rule_rust?

Tags: rust, bazel, rustfmt

I noticed bazel doesn't pick up rustfmt.toml from the project/target folder. What is the way to edit fmt parameters for bazel build?

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution to you problem is described [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/issues/388). When you follow the instructions you code can be formatted using:

```
bazel run :format_fix
```